# How to accumulate 1 to 10 in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to accumulate 1 to 10 in tensorflow. But it does not work.
Can anyone help me in fixing this.

```
one = tf.constant(1)
value = tf.Variable(0,name="value")
increasing_op = tf.add(value,one)
assign_op = tf.assign(value,increasing_op)

#sum
sumvalue = tf.Variable(0,name = "sumvalue")
sum_op = tf.add(sumvalue,assign_op)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    for _ in range(10):
        session.run(sum_op)
    print(session.run(sumvalue))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum_op` returns the value after the computation. Also you could take advantage of `tf.assign_add`:

```
sumvalue = tf.Variable(0,name = "sumvalue")
sum_op = tf.assign_add(sumvalue, 1)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    for _ in range(10):
        sum_value = session.run(sum_op)
    print(sum_value)
```

Comment: Hi pfm, Thanks for your help.
I revised the code like below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I revised the code like below

```
n = int(input("Enter an integer: "))

one=tf.constant(1)
#increase
increasing_value=tf.Variable(0,name="increasing_value")
increasing_op=tf.assign_add(increasing_value,one)

#sum
sumvalue=tf.Variable(0,name="sumvalue")
sum_op=tf.assign_add(sumvalue,increasing_value)

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    for _ in range (n):
        session.run(increasing_op)
        session.run(sum_op)
    print(session.run(sumvalue))
```

is it possible to use placeholder for n